# Como seria a estrutura de grandes projetos Java

Tags: java, aplicação-web, projeto-de-software, erp

Em pequenos projetos web, geralmente separamos pacotes em DAO, Models e Controllers, mas em grandes sistemas do tipo *ERP*, com centenas de tabelas, controllers e lógicas de negócios, como ficaria essa estrutura?

Comment: Se o projeto é pequeno essas coisas que citou sõa canhões para matar passarinho. Alguns projetos modernos (feitos por engenheiros de verdade que não fazem só porque está todo mundo fazendo) já não usam essas coisas nem em projetos grandes quando eles não fazem sentido para aquele projeto. Então a pergunta já parte de premissa errada., ou pelo menos ruim. Talvez e só talvez o grande mostra como é uma loucura fazer uma arquitetura complexa dessas. No pequeno só parece ser tranquilo porque ele é tão pequeno que dá quase na mesma, afinal a pessoa só copia e cola coisas.

Comment: @Maniero o sentido da pergunta é de como seria a estruturação desses projetos. É somente uma dúvida. Lógico que não faria sentido utilizar isso para um projeto pequeno só por moda.

Answer (score 3):

## Depende da arquitetura, que depende dos requisitos

A resposta é independente da linguagem, observe que poderia ser C# ou outra, tendo em vista que os conceitos citados como DAO, Models e Controllers (imaginei MVC), não são específicos, próprios ou exclusivos para software desenvolvido em Java.

DAO, por exemplo, é um instrumento para implementar a camada de persistência de um software ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)), assim como o padrão repository (esta [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550124/what-is-the-difference-between-dao-and-repository-patterns) do Stackoverflow esclarece a diferença entre ambos). Ou seja, são estratégias possíveis para lidar com o acesso a dados. O uso (qual delas empregar?), contudo, ou a indicação, vai depender do contexto (nenhuma delas é absolutamente melhor que a outra).

A pergunta tem como foco a arquitetura do software que, por sua vez, depende dos requisitos do software em questão. Veja que, caso empregue uma arquitetura baseada em micro-serviços, por exemplo, é possível que você não tenha mais "centenas de tabelas", mas um número menor por micro-serviço, o que talvez permita abordagens distintas por micro-serviço.

Enfim, se consultar alguns projetos do seu interesse no Github, provavelmente detectará que cada um possui uma arquitetura distinta dos demais, talvez alguns façam uso de DAO, por exemplo, enquanto outros não.